# Xorg fails to start under Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg

I'm running desktop Ubuntu 9.10 on my Dell laptop. Previously it was Ubuntu 9.04. After some period of time (lets say 3-4 months) my X fails to start automatically after some restart calls. If that takes place my network manager applet doesn't start either (after I do startx). Can any one point out what I'm missing/what's the problem?

**EDDITED**
I get a perfect server boot meaning there's no Xorg started. Command line interface is all I get starting from login and further.

Comment: more information please. what do you mean, 'x doesn't start'? does your laptop boot up to a text command line? does X start, but nothing displays on your screen? what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like something has changed your runlevel, and perhaps your system is out of date. try running `apt-get upgrade` and then `apt-get dist-upgrade` look at `/etc/inittab` and check the default runlevel. i'm not sure which runlevel on ubuntu represents gui login, but basic googling shows the line /might/ need to look like `id:3:initdefault:`